# Make using statement usable for multiple disposable objects

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, enumeration

I have a bunch of text files in a folder, and all of them should have identical headers. In other words the first 100 lines of all files should be identical. So I wrote a function to check this condition:

```
private static bool CheckHeaders(string folderPath, int headersCount)
{
    var enumerators = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
        .Select(f => File.ReadLines(f).GetEnumerator())
        .ToArray();
    //using (enumerators)
    //{
        for (int i = 0; i < headersCount; i++)
        {
            foreach (var e in enumerators)
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) return false;
            }
            var values = enumerators.Select(e => e.Current);
            if (values.Distinct().Count() > 1) return false;
        }
        return true;
    //}
}
```

The reason I am using enumerators is memory efficiency. Instead of loading all file contents in memory I enumerate the files concurrently line-by-line until a mismatch is found, or all headers have been examined.

My problem is evident by the commented lines of code. I would like to utilize a [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) block to safely dispose all the enumerators, but unfortunately `using (enumerators)` doesn't compile. Apparently `using` can handle only a single disposable object. I know that I can dispose the enumerators manually, by wrapping the whole thing in a `try-finally` block, and running the disposing logic in a loop inside finally, but is seems awkward. Is there any mechanism I could employ to make the `using` statement a viable option in this case?

---

**Update**

I just realized that my function has a serious flaw. The construction of the enumerators is not robust. A locked file can cause an exception, while some enumerators have already been created. These enumerators will not be disposed. This is something I want to fix. I am thinking about something like this:

```
var enumerators = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
    .ToDisposables(f => File.ReadLines(f).GetEnumerator());
```

The extension method `ToDisposables` should ensure that in case of an exception no disposables are left undisposed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193938/discussion-on-question-by-theodor-zoulias-make-using-statement-usable-for-multip).

Comment: What do you mean "_locked_" in "_A locked file can cause an exception_"?

Comment: @Alex I mean locked for reading. For example a file already opened from another application with the flag [`FileShare.None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileshare) will cause an exception when I try to open it from my application.

Comment: I see. `var enumerators = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath).Select(f =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return File.ReadLines(f).GetEnumerator();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                }).Where(f => f != null).ToArray();` helped me with files locked this way.

Comment: @Alex in this case you'll have a swallowed exception and a null enumerator. In my case I want to be informed that a file is locked so that I can unlock it and invoke my function again. A partial check of the headers of some files is not useful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a disposable-wrapper over your `enumerators`:

```
class DisposableEnumerable : IDisposable
{
    private IEnumerable<IDisposable> items;

    public event UnhandledExceptionEventHandler DisposalFailed;

    public DisposableEnumerable(IEnumerable<IDisposable> items) => this.items = items;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            try
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var tmp = DisposalFailed;
                tmp?.Invoke(this, new UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(e, false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it with the lowest impact to your code:

```
private static bool CheckHeaders(string folderPath, int headersCount)
{
    var enumerators = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
        .Select(f => File.ReadLines(f).GetEnumerator())
        .ToArray();

    using (var disposable = new DisposableEnumerable(enumerators))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < headersCount; i++)
        {
            foreach (var e in enumerators)
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) return false;
            }
            var values = enumerators.Select(e => e.Current);
            if (values.Distinct().Count() > 1) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The thing is you have to dispose those objects separately one by one anyway. But it's up to you where to encapsulate that logic. And the code I've suggested has no manual `try-finally`**,)**

Comment: I like your solution! I guess that `using (new DisposableEnumerable(enumerators))` should work as well.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, you are totally right. As long as you don't have to refer to the variable in the `using` block, you can keep it anonymous like that.

Comment: @Alex, I'm simulating `System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` I set a breakpoint inside of `Dispose` method but I can't get into it. Is it normal behaviour? If yes, how can I assure that the objects were disposed?

Comment: @Dmitry Stepanov, can you give me more contex? _'I set a breakpoint inside of `Dispose` method'_. Which line?

Comment: @Alex, I tried to set on all lines of `Dispose` method. I "lock" the file by another app and the exception throws on line `var enumerators = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath).Select(f => File.ReadLines(f).GetEnumerator()).ToArray();` So, that's why I can't understand how your solution works.

Comment: @Dmitry Stepanov, if you mean, you can't get into `DisposableEnumerable.Dispose()`, that's because an instance of one does not exist where you get the exception. That exception is a part of __expected behavior__. The OP wants to handle files __all or none__. That is widely mentioned in the question, the answers and the comments here. To enumerate `Disposable`s you'd better use `ToDisposable` method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56680767/10958092).

Comment: @Alex, I got it. Thanks a lot. Great answer! + 1.

Comment: @Dmitry Stepanov, thank you! I'm glad to know my answers are helpful!

Comment: @Dmitry Stepanov, there would be no answer without the question. I believe the question is underestimated. So, could you upvote it too?

Comment: @Alex, I agree with you. I upvoted the question a few days ago and even marked it as my favorite.

Answer (score 3):

To the second part of the question. If I get you right this should be sufficient:

```
static class DisposableHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> ToDisposable<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TResult> selector) where TResult : IDisposable
    {
        var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
        var result = new List<TResult>();
        foreach (var i in source)
        {
            try { result.Add(selector(i)); }
            catch (Exception e) { exceptions.Add(e); }
        }

        if (exceptions.Count == 0)
            return result;

        foreach (var i in result)
        {
            try { i.Dispose(); }
            catch (Exception e) { exceptions.Add(e); }
        }

        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private static bool CheckHeaders(string folderPath, int headersCount)
{
    var enumerators = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
                               .ToDisposable(f => File.ReadLines(f).GetEnumerator())
                               .ToArray();

    using (new DisposableEnumerable(enumerators))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < headersCount; i++)
        {
            foreach (var e in enumerators)
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) return false;
            }
            var values = enumerators.Select(e => e.Current);
            if (values.Distinct().Count() > 1) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
try
{
    CheckHeaders(folderPath, headersCount);
}
catch(AggregateException e)
{
    // Prompt to fix errors and try again
}
```

Comment: Now you've covered all cases of my problem, but contrary to your [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672160/11178549) this one is not general. I am interested for a general solution that can be applied in every case where a list of disposables must be safely created and finally disposed. Until now your [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672160/11178549) is my primary candidate to become the accepted one. 

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, I've improved the solution to make it generic.

Comment: We have a winner! I accepted your first answer, because it stands on its own. This one isn't because it doesn't contain the definition of `DisposableEnumerable`.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, great, thank you! I'm glad my solution is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Alex for taking the time to implement a solution. I was expecting that this question would be well received, but for unknown reasons turned out to be quite unpopular. 

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, yes the situation about voting makes me sad. The question is interesting and useful. As I see it's a battle. Up-voters (including me) vs. down-voters 4:7. Not so bad. On the bright side it's +6 reputation.

Comment: My guess is that some downvoters may dislike the idea of reading from multiple files concurrently, some may disagree that disposing the enumerators is required, and some may just feel uncomfortable discussing about some limitation that looks like a shortcoming of the C# language.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, that's sad but true. People tend to hate things they are uncomfortable with or they do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest an approach that uses recursive calls to `Zip` to allow parallel enumeration of a normal `IEnumerable<string>` without the need to resort to using `IEnumerator<string>`.

```
bool Zipper(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> sources, int take)
{
    IEnumerable<string> ZipperImpl(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ss)
        => (!ss.Skip(1).Any())
            ? ss.First().Take(take)
            : ss.First().Take(take).Zip(
                ZipperImpl(ss.Skip(1)),
                (x, y) => (x == null || y == null || x != y) ? null : x);

    var matching_lines = ZipperImpl(sources).TakeWhile(x => x != null).ToArray();
    return matching_lines.Length == take;
}
```

Now build up your `enumerables`:

```
IEnumerable<string>[] enumerables =
    Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(folderPath)
        .Select(f => File.ReadLines(f))
        .ToArray();
```

Now it's simple to call:

```
bool headers_match = Zipper(enumerables, 100);
```

Here's a trace of running this code against three files with more than 4 lines:

```
Ben Petering at 5:28 PM ACST 
Ben Petering at 5:28 PM ACST 
Ben Petering at 5:28 PM ACST 
  From a call 2019-05-23, James mentioned he’d like the ability to edit the current shipping price rules (eg in shipping_rules.xml) via the admin. 
  From a call 2019-05-23, James mentioned he’d like the ability to edit the current shipping price rules (eg in shipping_rules.xml) via the admin. 
  From a call 2019-05-23, James mentioned he’d like the ability to edit the current shipping price rules (eg in shipping_rules.xml) via the admin. 
He also mentioned he’d like to be able to set different shipping price rules for a given time window, e.g. Jan 1 to Jan 30.
He also mentioned he’d like to be able to set different shipping price rules for a given time window, e.g. Jan 1 to Jan 30.
He also mentioned he’d like to be able to set different shipping price rules for a given time window, e.g. Jan 1 to Jan 30.
These storyishes should be considered when choosing the appropriate module to use.
These storyishes should be considered when choosing the appropriate module to use.X
These storyishes should be considered when choosing the appropriate module to use.
```

Note that the enumerations stop when they encountered a mismatch header in the 4th line on the second file. All enumerations then stopped.

Comment: Upvoted for being an ingenious alternative solution for my specific problem, although it doesn't solve the thematic problem caused by the limitations of the `using` statement. For example if I wanted to append lines concurrently to all files I would need an open `StreamWriter` for each file that would had to be disposed at the end, and LINQ couldn't help me in that case (because LINQ is for reading, not writing).

Comment: I made some performance tests, and observed an exponential overhead from the recursion. For 500 files the overhead is around 2 sec in my machine. For 1000 files it becomes 15 sec. For 2000 files it becomes 120 sec, etc.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I didn't do any performance testing. I would normally try to prevent compounding `Skip` calls. Try replacing `ZipperImpl(ss.Skip(1))` with `ZipperImpl(ss.Skip(1).ToArray())` and see if that changes the performance.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Also keep in mind that with 2000 files being read one line at a time it might be that there's significant disk thrashing going on.

Comment: I added `.ToArray()` and, yeap, it's much better. Now the overhead is 2 sec at 3000 files, and grows more slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Creating an `IDisposable` wrapper as @Alex suggested is correct. It needs just a logic to dispose already opened files if some of them is *locked* and probably some logic for error states. Maybe something like this (error state logic is very simple):

```cs
public class HeaderChecker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly string _folderPath;
    private readonly int _headersCount;
    private string _lockedFile;
    private readonly List<IEnumerator<string>> _files = new List<IEnumerator<string>>();

    public HeaderChecker(string folderPath, int headersCount)
    {
        _folderPath = folderPath;
        _headersCount = headersCount;
    }

    public string LockedFile => _lockedFile;

    public bool CheckFiles()
    {
        _lockedFile = null;
        if (!TryOpenFiles())
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (_files.Count == 0)
        {
            return true; // Not sure what to return here.
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _headersCount; i++)
        {
            if (!_files[0].MoveNext()) return false;
            string currentLine = _files[0].Current;

            for (int fileIndex = 1; fileIndex < _files.Count; fileIndex++)
            {
                if (!_files[fileIndex].MoveNext()) return false;
                if (_files[fileIndex].Current != currentLine) return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private bool TryOpenFiles()
    {
        bool result = true;
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(_folderPath))
        {
            try
            {
                _files.Add(File.ReadLines(file).GetEnumerator());
            }
            catch
            {
                _lockedFile = file;
                result = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!result)
        {
            DisposeCore(); // Close already opened files.
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void DisposeCore()
    {
        foreach (var item in _files)
        {
            try
            {
                item.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        _files.Clear();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeCore();
    }
}

// Usage
using (var checker = new HeaderChecker(folderPath, headersCount))
{
    if (!checker.CheckFiles())
    {
        if (checker.LockedFile is null)
        {
            // Error while opening files.
        }
        else
        {
            // Headers do not match.
        }
    }
}
```

I also removed `.Select()` and `.Distinct()` when checking the lines. The first just iterates over the `enumerators` array - the same as `foreach` above it, so you are enumerating this array twice. Then creates a new list of lines and `.Distinct()` enumerates over it.

Comment: Thanks @StanoPeťko! I upvoted your answer for being a complete solution to my specific problem. It ensures that all of my enumerators are disposed in all cases. I can't mark it as the accepted answer though, because it lacks generality. I am expecting a solution that can by applied in every case where a list of disposables must be safely created and finally disposed.

Comment: Well. The wrapper class would need some _creator_ of those `IDisposable` objects as an input so it can create them and handle errors. It needs some other action to process created items. But those items can be anything if you want it general. So processing action must know what type it is working with. The process itself may want to return anything not just bool. I believe all of this is possible, but such a wrapper class should be generic than (probably more than one generic type) and using of that would be quite complicated. Or what kind of generality you expect?

Comment: Making the wrapper generic sounds like a good idea! I agree that making it too complicated will defeat the purpose of this exercise. The `using` statement is supposed to exists to simplify things, not to make them even more complicated!

Comment: Ideally I would like to have an extension method `ToDisposables` that could be used in place of a `ToArray` or `ToList` in a LINQ query, and then be able to use the result of this method directly in a `using` statement: `using (enumerators) { ... }`.