# combining/consolidating using statements - c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have several `using` statements in method like

```
 public List<Object> MethodA(){

 using ( someclassTypeA var1 = IdentifierClass.Object1.createObject())
 using ( someclassTypeB var2 = IdentifierClass.Object2.createObject())
 using ( someclassTypeC var3 = IdentifierClass.Object3.createObject())
 ...
 //20 of these using statements
 ...
 //test code
}
```

and I'll be having several test methods like that when I add more tests. So it will look not so good in one file.

Is there a way I can shorten that `using` code , maybe get `using` statements  from some other class or something?

Comment: You could simply not use `using` and explicitly call `Dispose` in a loop in a `finally` instead. `using` is intended to be convenient; don't use it if it's not. That said -- I really question any code that finds itself with a need to create so many individually named disposable objects. Do they need to be disposable? If they do, why do you need 20 of them? If you need 20 of them, do they each need to be named individually?

Comment: I am new to C#. I think they would need to be disposable thats why they used `using` . There are so many as these are individual elements (like `button`, `radioBoutton` , `menuItem` etc..) of UI app and thats why they need to be named individually.

Comment: Disposing of controls is usually done by having them owned by a container (e.g. all controls on a `Form` are disposed by the `Form`, when *it* is disposed). With ownership semantics like that in place there's typically no need to dispose of anything but the top-level container. However, if you're testing a UI setup this is probably the wrong approach -- separate your UI code from your logic code so you can test your logic without creating controls, and use [coded UI tests](https://docs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code) if you need to test the UI itself.

Comment: So just to be sure that I provided all info - the tests uses ranorex libraries to drive. Test code is all together separate from application UI code.

Comment: Do you have the same block for every test or is it different controls each test?

Comment: If you are dealing with an array or list of disposable objects, look at this question: [Make using statement usable for multiple disposable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309952/make-using-statement-usable-for-multiple-disposable-objects)

Comment: @user1207289 *I think they would need to be disposable* -- **Why** do you think that? Do you understand the `IDisposable` pattern and why and when to use it?

Comment: @Daniel Mann Currently I do not fully understand to answer your why. But I would like to . Do you have a reference , where I can look?

Comment: @nvoigt  the block may be different with some elements same

Answer (score 3):

I would submit that you *could* wrap all this in a shared class, so you dont have to repeat this all over

```
public class SharedContainer : IDisposible
{
    public someclassTypeA Var1 {get;}
    public someclassTypeB Var2 {get;}
    public someclassTypeC Var3 {get;}

    public SharedContainer()
    {
       Var1 = IdentifierClass.Object1.createObject();
       Var2 = IdentifierClass.Object2.createObject();
       Var3 = IdentifierClass.Object3.createObject();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       Var1.Dispose();
       Var2.Dispose();
       Var3.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now in your client code you just have 1 `using`:

```
using(var shared = new SharedContainer())
{
    shared.Var1.... // whatever
}
```

But if you need to do this, I suggest you have bigger problems.

Comment: I will try this approach

Answer (score 0):

In C# 8 you could use one line:

```
using var x = IdentifierClass.Object1.createObject();
using var y = IdentifierClass.Object2.createObject();
using var z = IdentifierClass.Object3.createObject();
```