# How to dispose an array of IDisposables returned by a task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, using, idisposable

I use the rule of thumb to always put inside a using statement everything that implements IDisposable. But I'm starting to work with Tasks and I can't add a using statement like this:

```
var getResultTasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

getResultTasks.Add(_client.GetAsync(requestUri));
getResultTasks.Add(_client.GetAsync(requestUri));

using var httpGetResponseMessages = await Task.WhenAll(getResultTasks);
```

It says:

> 'HttpResponseMessage[]': type used in a using statement must be
> implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'.

I can apply it without problems to a single instance though:

```
using var testing = await _client.GetAsync("");
```

Comment: You could take a look at this: [Do I need to dispose of Tasks?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/) Spoiler alert: *“No. Don’t bother disposing of your tasks.”*

Comment: Related: [Make using statement usable for multiple disposable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309952/make-using-statement-usable-for-multiple-disposable-objects) (one of my own first questions in this site)

Answer (score 1):

Since .net core 3, calling `Dispose` on a http `HttpResponseMessage` may not always be needed.

In short, In the majority of cases the body of the response from the underlying connection *Socket* is fully received, and the byte data representing the content will be buffered into a `MemoryStream` automatically. This occurs when using most overloads of the `HttpClient` APIs (`GetAsync`, `PostAsync` and `SendAsync`).

Calling dispose will only dispose the underlying `MemoryStream` which is not needed. **However, there are cases where this is not true**, so if you do not completely understand what is going on, call `Dispose` on a `HttpResponseMessage`. In your case you have a list of `HttpResponseMessage`, then just loop through the list manually

```
var responses = await Task.WhenAll(getResultTasks);

foreach(var response in response)
{
   // do something with the result maybe

   response?.Dispose();

   // job done
}
```

Comment: I read that a foreach disposes automatically (link at the end). By the way, isn't it possible to use the using operator somehow so the IDisposable is automatically disposed https://csharpindepth.com/articles/IteratorBlockImplementation#:~:text=The%20foreach%20statement%20in%20C%23,sure%20that%20Dispose%20is%20called.